# How to fix lsp-pyright type hint errors; "int" is incompatible with "float"?

Tags: python, pyright

Using this python example snippet below, I'm getting the error at the bottom

```
from typing import List
def foo(x:List[float]):
    pass

i=[3]
foo(i)
```

.

```
[Pyright] Argument of type "list[int]" cannot be assigned to parameter "x" of type "List[float]" in function "foo"
  TypeVar "_T@list" is invariant
    "int" is incompatible with "float" (5:4)
```

lsp-pyright: 20220614.1545

---

[PEP 484 *Type Hints*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-numeric-tower) specifically states that:

> Rather than requiring that users write import numbers and then use `numbers.Float` etc., this PEP proposes a straightforward shortcut that is almost as effective: **when an argument is annotated as having type `float`, an argument of type `int` is acceptable**; similar, for an argument annotated as having type complex, arguments of type float or int are acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

`3` is an integer literal. While Python will generally transparently convert from integer to float if necessary, since you typed your code as `float` the typechecker wants a float.

Just use a float literal: `3.0`, or just `3.` (but it's a bit less readable).

> PEP 484 Type Hints specifically states that:

Feel free to report the issue to pyright, possibly linked to / following up on [issue 260](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/260).

However note that the argument is not annotated as having type `float` here, it's annotated as having type `List[float]`, which is not quite the same situation (cf the [variance](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#covariance-and-contravariance) section of PEP 484).